# Force type in API Platform (int to string)

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I try to pass data from React to PHP using API Platform but the problem is that my fetch from database returns some values that are integers and API Platform won't accept those int and expects string instead.

My question is, how can I force those values to be returned as string when I do the GET from API Platform ?

Should I modify them after with the javascrip String() ? Doesn't look like the way to go in my opinion...

For information, here is the error I get :

> ApiPlatform\Serializer\AbstractItemNormalizer::canAccessAttributePostDenormalize(): Argument #3 ($attribute) must be of type string, int given, called in /var/www/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Serializer/AbstractItemNormalizer.php on line 365

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force some json value to string you could create CustomNormalizer for following subject, that supports only this single Class (or even serialization group):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html

```php
    public function normalize($topic, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($topic, $format, $context);

        // Here parse value to string
        $data['propertyName'] = (string) $data['propertyName'];

        return $data;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $data instanceof YourClass;
    }
```

Comment: So API Platform can only be sent string values by default if I understand correctly ? So I have to create custom normalizers ?

Comment: No, I believe it was determined by property type defined in class, and if there is no type before property then it could parse only by its value. If you add ` private int $someProp` then all results will be `integer`